# Run foreman inside of intellij

Tags: heroku, intellij-idea, foreman

I'm able to run Heroku foreman no problem from my windows command line but I'm having trouble figuring out how to run it inside of IntelliJ.  I attempted to enable the "Batch Support" plugin but it crashes when I start up IntelliJ.  I also tried to run it through the "Command Line Tools" plugin but that couldn't find foreman.

How can I successfully run Heroku foreman inside of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...created an external tool at Settings -> External Tools (see below).  Can then run by selecting Tools -> foreman

[image: foreman-intellij-setup]